# Not able to GET file in chrome via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am learning AJAX in vanilla js.
I am made a get request(AJAX) by the following code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
console.log('ready!');
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4)
        document.getElementById('file-data').innerText = xhr.responseText;
    xhr.send();
}
xhr.open('GET', 'file:///E:ada/kk.js', true);
});
```

This works perfectly in Firefox but in chrome I am getting following errors:-

```
kk.js:7 Failed to load file:///E:/ada/kk.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

xhr.onreadystatechange @ kk.js:7

```
kk.js:7 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (file:///E:/ada/kk.js:7:9)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (file:///E:/ada/kk.js:7:9)
at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (file:///E:/ada/kk.js:9:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are loading your file from your local machine, and as it isn't an http call you get the cors error message

You should host your file somewhere in an url like 
`http://example.com/path/to/file` or else serve it in a local server